# How to update android sms conversation thread?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I wanted to update the "message_count" column and "snippet" column of a sms conversation thread, using this content:"content://mms-sms/conversations". Because the snippet and message count is not updated when an SMS is deleted from the conversation thread.
But I got this error message: "MmsSmsProvider does not support deletes, inserts, or updates for this URI"
Below is my code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("message_count", ent.getValue().getCount());
values.put("snippet", ent.getValue().getSnip());

Uri conUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");
getContentResolver().update(conUri, values, null, null);
```

I also try like this:

```
Uri conUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations" + "/" + threadid);
getContentResolver().update(conUri, values, null, null);
```

But what I got is another error message:no such column: message_count: , while compiling: UPDATE pdu SET message_count=?,snippet=? WHERE thread_id=334

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to update the count, snippet etc of a thread directly. But I can help you with your actual problem. There is actually a bug in the android code, which is the root of your issue. When you try to delete in the following way -

```
getContentResolver().delete("content://sms/", "_id=?", new String[] {id});
```

Android does not update the thread associated with that sms.

The solution is is to do this

```
getContentResolver().delete("content://sms/" + id, null, null);
```

For those who are curious what the bug is - 
Android code does something stupid like this, when you delete using method 1 -

1. Delete all messages given by the query.
2. Get all the conversation threads associated with the messages given by the query and update them. Whoa wat ?! Step 1 just deleted messages given by query so, step 2 is always going to return a null set for threads associated with those message, as all the messages are already deleted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not a bug, sms/mms URIs are not part of the official public api and are therefore not expected to work like other URIs. Also, what you gave as the description of the bug is incorrect. the `threads` table is not updated via URIs but through triggers in the sqlite db.

Comment: hi @vikki, i have a same problem with updating `sms/conversations`, how can update that? did you know? after i delete `sms` from sms Uri an put back, i can't get snippet from conversations, because it's null, i tried update that but it's return no such column, did you know how an fix this?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan maybe I'm not understanding your situation, you say that after deleting an sms, you add another and then after adding that, the `snippet` column is null?

Comment: @vikki thanks for answer, my situation is something like restore, after restore one sms, snippet column is null. I just remove sms from sms table, but i think this deleted from conversation too and i can't update that value,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan you need to make sure that the sms is actually being restored/inserted. I'd advise you to inspect the database directly using an sqlite client that has a gui. Personally I use [this firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). The sqlite db where SMSs/MMSs are stored can be found at `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/` and it is called `mmssms.db`. Looking at this db will give you a deeper understanding of how sms/mms works in android.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Finally I should point out that as long as the sms is being inserted, the snippet is guaranteed to be generated because it relies on an sql trigger and not android or your code. Let me know if you still get stuck.

Comment: @vikki I have deleted successfully from Database and save all Sms in my database ( that is same with SMS table) , i restore that successfully to SMS table from my table, but conversation snippet is null, and thread_id is not null, I can ignore this problem in my app but i want fix that, maybe other app want's use that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan there must be something wrong with how you're doing the insert, the sms is most likely not being stored properly. Can I see some code?

Comment: yes @vikki, you right, thank for help, I figure out my problem